# Steam API - Replace id's with Schema

Tags: php, json, api, steam

I find solution for getting id's from API to my website.

But, I still don't know how to replace this: (from http://api.steampowered.com/IEconItems_440/GetPlayerItems/v0001/?key=APIKEY&steamid=76561198108107219&format=json)

```
"id": 1960542190,
"defindex": 744,
```

With this: (from http://api.steampowered.com/IEconItems_440/GetSchema/v0001/?key=APIKEY)

```
"name": "Pyrovision Goggles",
"defindex": 744,
```

I'm using this:

```
     $url = "http://api.steampowered.com/IEconItems_440/GetPlayerItems/v0001/?key=" . $api_key . "&steamid=" . $idc . "&format=json";
     $json_object= file_get_contents($url);
     $json_decoded = json_decode($json_object);

      foreach ($json_decoded->result->items as $item)
      {
          $items[$item->id]['id'] = $item->id;
          $items[$item->id]['original_id'] = $item->original_id;
          $items[$item->id]['defindex'] = $item->defindex;
          $items[$item->id]['level'] = $item->level;
          $items[$item->id]['quality'] = $item->quality;


          echo $item->defindex; echo "<br>";
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the player's inventory, now you need to pull the Item Schema.

```
 $url = "http://api.steampowered.com/IEconItems_440/GetSchema/v0001/?key=" $APIKEY;
 $json_object= file_get_contents($url);
 $schema_json_decoded = json_decode($json_object);
 $items_schema = $schema_json_decoded->result->items;
```

The schema items are now in the `$items` variable. In your `foreach` loop, we need to compare the `defindex` of the player's item with the `defindex`es in the schema:

```
foreach ($json_decoded->result->items as $item)
  {
      ...
      $items[$item->id]['defindex'] = $item->defindex;
      ...

      foreach ($items_schema as $item)
      {
          if ($items[$item->id]['defindex'] == $item->defindex)
          {
              $items[$item->id]['name'] = $item->item_name;
          }
      }
  }
```

Your item name is now stored in `$items[$item->id]['name']`.

Comment: Now I'm getting: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'as' (T_AS), expecting ';'

Comment: That second for should be a foreach as well

Comment: Hi Could someone post a corrected code please?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What's wrong with this code Daniel? The `foreach` mentioned in the previous comment has been fixed.